# Cardinality of natural join and left join

Tags: logic, relations, relation-algebra

Let $M$ and $N$ be relations.

I want to calculate the lower and upper bound of $M\Join N$ and $M\ltimes N$.

$$$$

I have done the following :

- As for $M\Join N$ :

If $M$ and $N$ contain have common columns and same rows at these columns, then the natural join consider these rows and take all combinations, right?

Is this like cartesian product?

- As for $M\ltimes N$ :

The result contains the tuples of $M$ that have at least a common column with $N$, right?

If all tuples of $M$ have common columns with $N$ then the upper bound is $m$.

If no tuple of $M$ has common columns with $N$ then the lower bound is $0$.

Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation or the terminology "left join" and "natural join". I think you're more likely to get an answer if you give the definitions.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: They're relational algebra terms, but more commonly associated [with SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

Answer (score 1):

For the natural join you are right.
The upper bound is $|M| \times |N|$ (in case all the tuples join), and the lower bound is $0$ (in case no tuple join).

For the left join you have to take into account that a left join returns the natural join between M and N, together all those tuples from M that do not join any tuple from N.

Hence, the upper bound is $max(|M|, |M| \times |N|)$ (it will be $|M|$, for instance, if no tuple from M joins N), and the lower bound is $|M|$ (in case no tuple from M joins N).